# How to connect to mysql created in docker from windows machine

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Docker-toolbox on windows. How to connect to the database from a program like WorkBench?

```
version: "3.1"

services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    command: --innodb_use_native_aio=0
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - //c/Users/radik/projects/laravel/storage/docker/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 123456
    ports:
      - 33061:3306
```

I'm trying to connect to the database from HeidiSql

```
host:192.168.99.100
name: root
port: 33061
```

result:

```
Cannot connect to MySQL server
```

Comment: Docker-toolbox doesn't use your default PC IP (192.168.99.100). Docker will create new "virtual" IPs for your VM machine where the Docker container/s  is/are executing. Probably the 'ipconfig' conmmand will provide you the information you need.

Comment: 192.168.99.100 its not my machine ip. 
This is ip i take from  `docker-machine ip default` command

Answer (score 1):

you have 33333:3306 in your config so you should connect to port 33333 not 33061 right?

Comment: Im sorry. Typo in question. Edited

Answer (score 0):

If docker runs on your local machine, you can just use localhost (127.0.0.1) as host.

Comment: I have windows machine